# SelectedIndexChanged not firing on any list control on live server

Tags: asp.net, iis, selectedindexchanged

I have a dropdown on my master page that lets the user switch language at runtime from any page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cmbCulture" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Small" EnableViewState="true"
    AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbCulture_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Global" Value="en" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Swedish" Value="sv" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="German" Value="de" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="USA" Value="en-US" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

When running this on my local machine through VS2010 it works fine and `SelectedIndexChanged` gets fired when changing language.
However, when deploying this to live server (running IIS 7.5) and entering the address to my site e.g. http://www.mysite.com/ the `SelectedIndexChanged` does NOT get fired, not on any list control UNLESS I enter the full URL to my site: http://www.mysite.com/**default.aspx**. Then it works!

How and why?
I have the same site running on another server with IIS7 (I think) and the event is fired when entering only _http://www.mysite.com/

I suspect this is due to some setting in IIS 7.5 since the site is basically a copy of the old site, but which setting could cause something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search the "Event Handlers Might Not Be Not Raised in a Default Document in IIS 7 or IIS 7.5 Integrated Mode" in below url

http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes

Comment: Thank you! My action-attribute on the form-tag was empty and setting it to "Default.aspx" fixed it.